# JDK 8u161 breaks JMX Integration

Tags: java, java-8, rmi

I'm working with a piece of code that's quite old. It works absolutely fine with the versions of Java older than 8u161.

This is the error I get on 8u161 and beyond releases.

```
[main] ******** - Failed to create JmxConnectInfo!
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405)
```

This error is triggered from a class that extends javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer where I invoke the code

```
super.start()
```

I'm sure that this error is caused by [JDK-8159377](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8159377) but I'm unable to figure a way out!

Can someone pls advise?

Comment: Have you checked the source code of RMIJRMPServerImpl? On my system line 150 is the call to  `env.get(RMIExporter.EXPORTER_ATTRIBUTE).exportObject(obj, port, csf, ssf, typeFilter)` (combined with line 140/141).

Comment: What makes you so sure that this error is caused by JDK-8159377?

Comment: Could you please share standalone test case to validate this issue?